# AWS lambda : "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'datadog_lambda'"

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, datadog

I am trying to import datadog_lambda.metric :

from datadog_lambda.metric import lambda_metric

and I see the below error :

{
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'datadog_lambda'",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
"requestId": "",
"stackTrace": []
}

I tried adding a datadog layer to my lambda function by attaching "datadog-lambda 4.72.0" and "pytz" package files to my layer, even after that I am still seeing same error.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be helpful, Thank you.